# how to navigate directories with heaps of files

Tags: linux, bash

My Linux file system has tens of thousands of files per directory. Viewing a list of all the files takes a few minutes for my system to calculate, which is too slow. But I am not sure what files are in each directory so want to view a list of the first few, like what the *head* command does for large files. Is there a command that efficiently does this?

Edit:
Piping **ls** to something else is no good because **ls** takes a few minutes to complete, before piping the output. I need a command that will only return the first few records.

Comment: Why so many files in a directory?

Comment: Does it matter? Anyway, it is downloaded web content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ls -f` which does not sort.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot faster, and doing `ls -f | sort | less` is way faster too! Madness.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the directories you can do the following by a shell script

Try this, this gives one page full of entries

```
ls | more
```

You can even push this to some file if you want so that you can refer to it later, for that use this

```
ls | more > filenames.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: +1 despite `more` used just before a redirection

Comment: "less is more" - If you have `less` use it instead of `more`

Comment: There is also "most" (someone had a hard time naming his program :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list N first entries, 
I would just create a small C program that does an opendir call and then N calls to readdir

Comment: that's the same as head the list of files. and head or ls are C programs

Comment: I would rather not create my own script because I would want a solution that works on a few machines, without having to copy my script around.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the filesystem, but it's usually quicker to list filenames only (look at the directory object) versus all the file metadata (saves one stat() per file).

Have you tried `ls -R`?

Otherwise, it might pay you to run the GNU locate program in the background periodically, and use the generated DB to track it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `head`:

```
ls -l | head
```